# How do I convert raw ascii values in string to integer?

Tags: python

I have a 128 bit value I'm storing as a string in python.  I would like to retrieve the last 4 bytes of it, increment it, and then put it back into the 128 bit value.  Example:

```
mybigvalue = "69dda8455c7dd4254bf353b773304eec".decode('hex')
lastInt = mybigvalue [12:]
lastInt =lastInt +1
mybigvalue [12:] = lastInt
```

This doesn't work though. I'm a python noob and not sure what to try next, or if my entire idea of doing this is wrong.  I come from a C background and do not totally understand how python treats data.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Is this your whole code? Where is `ctr` defined? What do you mean by "this doesn't work"? Does it crash, or what?

Comment: And are you interpreting those bytes as little or big endian? Signed or unsigned?

Comment: Python 2.7 and ctr was a typo from copy paste, i fixed it

Comment: what if last 4 bytes are ffffffff?

Comment: Roll over to 0 is fine, I'm not worried about the carry right now. Though It seems like it would be straightforward to code using the technique @MartijnPieters gave below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 2: use [`struct.unpack()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) to interpret those last 4 bytes as an integer:

```
import struct

lastInt = struct.unpack('<I', mybigvalue[-4:])[0]
lastInt += 1
mybigvalue = mybigvalue[:-4] + struct.pack('<I', lastInt & ((1 << 32) - 1))
```

`'<I'` means the bytes are interpreted as an unsigned integer, little-endian.

I also masked the value to fit within 32 bits; `ffffffff` will overflow to `00000000` that way.

Demo:

```
>>> import struct
>>> mybigvalue = "69dda8455c7dd4254bf353b773304eec".decode('hex')
>>> lastInt = struct.unpack('<I', mybigvalue[-4:])[0]
>>> lastInt += 1
>>> mybigvalue = mybigvalue[:-4] + struct.pack('<I', lastInt & ((1 << 32) - 1))
>>> print mybigvalue.encode('hex')
69dda8455c7dd4254bf353b774304eec
```

The `73304eec` incremented to `74304eec`; if you wanted `73304eed` instead, use big-endian; `'>I'`.

Comment: Though I suspect I'm trying to solve problems in python in a 'C' style way and their may be a better pythonian way to approach this form the beginning.